# ZoneId Europe/Berlin NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, timezone, java-time, tzdata

I wrote a DateUtil class that converts java.time.LocalDateTime to java.util.Date and backwards. When trying to get the system-Default TimeZone or a specific TimeZone (Europe/Berlin) I get an exception.
I checked that the JVM TimeZone is correctly configured, and it is.

Here is my simple code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    public static Date toDate(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
        return Date.from(dateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant());
    }

    public static Date toDate(LocalDate date) {
        return Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Invalid binary time-zone data: TZDB:Europe/Berlin, version: 2019c
    at java.time.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider.provideRules(TzdbZoneRulesProvider.java:141)
    at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:227)
    at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)
    at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
    at de.swkbank.camunda.ks.smarta.util.DateUtil.toDate(DateUtil.java:11)
    at de.swkbank.camunda.ks.smarta.delegate.WorkingHoursCalculator.getNextDate(WorkingHoursCalculator.java:16)
    at de.swkbank.camunda.ks.smarta.delegate.WorkingHoursCalculatorTest.test(WorkingHoursCalculatorTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition.getDateTimeAfter(ZoneOffsetTransition.java:287)
    at java.time.zone.ZoneRules.<init>(ZoneRules.java:292)
    at java.time.zone.ZoneRules.readExternal(ZoneRules.java:456)
    at java.time.zone.Ser.readInternal(Ser.java:194)
    at java.time.zone.Ser.read(Ser.java:188)
    at java.time.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider.provideRules(TzdbZoneRulesProvider.java:136)
    ... 40 more
```

Is there some misconfiguration on my computer? Its a Microsoft Surface with Win 10. JVM is RedHat JDK 1.8.0.242

Comment: This error is not reproducible, on my machine this runs without an exception. Try a different JDK.

Comment: "When trying to get the system-Default TimeZone" - so even a simple `ZoneId.systemDefault()` produces that NPE and even in an otherwise empty application? If so, could you post that as a [mcve] and maybe state some more info on your system/JVM setup? Did you try with another JVM?

Comment: I updated JVM to 1.8.0.292 (Red Hat). Still same error.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: See your [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6KVOLO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occured when mocking LocalDateTime::now. This results in the exception. I could solve the mocking by injecting a java.time.Clock to the now-Call and returning a fixed clock in the test.

Comment: Happens if you have 

`try (MockedStatic<LocalTime> mockedLocalDateTime = Mockito.mockStatic(LocalTime.class)) {
            mockedLocalDateTime.when(() -> LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))).thenReturn(currentTime);
assert()...`
Trick is to extract - `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` outside static context of the test(outside try in my case)

Comment: i am using a clock & it's already outside of the clock. i still see the error. thanks for the post anyway. it's good to know the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is going wrong exactly. But there seems to be a problem, perhaps corruption, in the tzdb (time zone database) that defines the time zones.

And your tzdb is out-of-date at version 2019c. I suggest you update your tzdb in your JDK, or just replace your entire JDK with a later version. Either way, you may see your error disappear.

---

By the way, you should try to phase out your use of `Date` and `Calendar` classes wherever possible. The *java.time* classes are intended to replace the legacy classes entirely. Convert back and forth where you must, to interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. But try to move on when you can. Those old classes really are that bad.